# Flutter Drag and Drop

Tags: flutter, dynamic, reference, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm facing a problem implementing drag and drop in my project.  I want dynamically add and delete draggable elements. The problem is that I can't understand how to get the reference to the widget I'm currently moving so that I can understand which coordinates in the list I have to change.

Here is an example of the code where I use the static number of draggable widgets. They are assigned with coordinates from the list. But what if I have to dynamically add and delete those draggable widgets how can I understand which coordinates to change?

So, I have an array of draggble elements and array of coordinates. Widget with index 0 refers to coordinates with index 0. How can I understand which widget I'm currently moving so that I can get the index of it in array of widgets and then change proper coordinates in array of coordinates.

```
class DragAndDrop extends StatefulWidget {
  const DragAndDrop({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  @override
  _DragAndDropState createState() => _DragAndDropState();
}

class _DragAndDropState extends State<DragAndDrop> {
  List<double?> _x = [0.0, 20.0];
  List<double?> _y = [0.0, 20.0];
  int k = -1;
  List<Widget> pel = [];

  final GlobalKey stackKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    pel.add(Container(color: Colors.blue));
    k++;
    Widget drag = Draggable<int>(
      data: k,
      child: Icon(
        Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
        color: Color(0x95000000),
        size: 40,
      ),
      feedback: Icon(
        Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
        color: Color.fromRGBO(212, 14, 14, 0.584),
        size: 40,
      ),
      childWhenDragging: Container(),
      onDragStarted: () {},
      onDragEnd: (dragDetails) {
        setState(() {
          final parentPos = stackKey.globalPaintBounds;
          if (parentPos == null) return;
          if (dragDetails.offset.dx - parentPos.left < 0)
            _x[0] = 0;
          else if (dragDetails.offset.dx - parentPos.left >
              double.parse(widget.width.toString()) - 40)
            _x[0] = double.parse(widget.width.toString()) - 40;
          else
            _x[0] = dragDetails.offset.dx - parentPos.left;
          if (dragDetails.offset.dy - parentPos.top < 0)
            _y[0] = 0;
          else if (dragDetails.offset.dy - parentPos.top >
              double.parse(widget.height.toString()) - 40)
            _y[0] = double.parse(widget.height.toString()) - 40;
          else
            _y[0] = dragDetails.offset.dy - parentPos.top;
        });
      },
    );
    pel.add(Positioned(
      left: _x[0],
      top: _y[0],
      child: drag,
    ));
    pel.add(Positioned(
      left: _x[1],
      top: _y[1],
      child: Draggable<int>(
        data: k,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
          color: Color(0x95000000),
          size: 40,
        ),
        feedback: Icon(
          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(212, 14, 14, 0.584),
          size: 40,
        ),
        childWhenDragging: Container(),
        onDragStarted: () {},
        onDragEnd: (dragDetails) {
          setState(() {
            final parentPos = stackKey.globalPaintBounds;
            if (parentPos == null) return;
            _x[1] = dragDetails.offset.dx - parentPos.left; // 11.
            _y[1] = dragDetails.offset.dy - parentPos.top;
           
          });
        },
      ),
    ));
    return Stack(
      key: stackKey,
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: pel,
    );
  }
}

extension GlobalKeyExtension on GlobalKey {
  Rect? get globalPaintBounds {
    final renderObject = currentContext?.findRenderObject();
    var translation = renderObject?.getTransformTo(null).getTranslation();
    if (translation != null && renderObject?.paintBounds != null) {
      return renderObject!.paintBounds
          .shift(Offset(translation.x, translation.y));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use a variable that I can assign to Dragble.data field but I'm not able to get it inside the widget.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still confuse do checkout [kanban_board](https://pub.dev/packages/kanban_board).
Its a good package to play with drag & drop.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kanban_board/custom/board.dart';
import 'package:kanban_board/models/inputs.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KanbanBoard(
      List.generate(
        8,
        (index) => BoardListsData(
            items: List.generate(
          50,
          (index) => Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. $index",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 19,
                    height: 1.3,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
          ),
        )),
      ),
      onItemLongPress: (cardIndex, listIndex) {},
      onItemReorder:
          (oldCardIndex, newCardIndex, oldListIndex, newListIndex) {},
      onListLongPress: (listIndex) {},
      onListReorder: (oldListIndex, newListIndex) {},
      onItemTap: (cardIndex, listIndex) {},
      onListTap: (listIndex) {},
      onListRename: (oldName, newName) {},
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      displacementY: 124,
      displacementX: 100,
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 19,
          height: 1.3,
          color: Colors.grey.shade800,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
    );
  }
}
```